# Cannot dualboot Linux (nothing helps)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, dual-boot, uefi

I konw I know. Probably the 1000th post about this but I really feel like I have tried everything.

Grub2Win, BootRepair. Manually reinstalling grub from live usb stick.. Nothing.

So A while ago I had a working dual boot with Windows 10 and Fedora. I wanted to swap to Ubuntu and dont really remember how I did it. Installed ubuntu and boom. no more fedora, no more ubuntu, just windows.

I tried grub2win added an entry to the drive I installed ubuntu on, but I could never get grub2win to boot.

In windows I deleted all the

If I go into the boot manager I see:

1. fedoragrubx64
2. gnugrubkernel64
3. fedora
4. Windows Boot Manager

which is infuriating and disappointing since I deleted all fedora related EFI stuff using `bcdedit /enum firmware` and `bcdedit /delete`.

I tried [this questions marked answer step by step](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

I tried boot-repair-disk. with the recommended settings.
Output is below.

I imagine I should clean this efi drive but I dont know how to without getting my windows nuked as well..

Also sorry if this is not the correct forum point me in the right direction.

```
boot-repair-4ppa203                                              [20230305_0007]

============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => Windows 7/8/10/11/2012 is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/fbia32.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/grubx64.efi /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/10/11/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10 or 11
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.03
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32784 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS on sda6
OS#2:   Windows 10 or 11 on sda4

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: HD Graphics 5500 GM108M [GeForce 940M] from Intel Corporation NVIDIA Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Boot-Repair-Disk 64bit 20200604, bionic, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: V1.25 from Insyde Corp.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,0003,0002,0004,000C,2002,2003
Boot0000* Unknown Device:   HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0001* USB HDD: KingstonDataTraveler 3.0 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(0,0)/USB(0,0)/HD(1,MBR,0x1e0567d,0x800,0x1cd125a)RC
Boot0002* gnugrubkernel64   PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\grub2win\g2bootmgr\gnugrub.kernel64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0003* fedoragrubx64 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\fedora\grubx64.efi)A01 ..
Boot0004* fedora    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1f,0x2)/Sata(0,0,0)/HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\fedora\shimx64.efi)A01 ).
Boot0005* Unknown Device:   HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0006* Unknown Device:   HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\Boot\grubx64.efi)RC
Boot0007* Unknown Device:   HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0008* Unknown Device:   HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0009* Unknown Device:   HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot000C* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)RC
Boot0012* Unknown Device:   HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)RC
Boot0014* ubuntu    HD(2,GPT,faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0,0xfa000,0x31800)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot2001* EFI USB Device    RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC

728124f6ec8e22fbdbe7034812c81b95   sda2/Boot/bkpbootx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/Boot/bootx64.efi
4d15fe872652d8e1782f1d3af11b1c77   sda2/Boot/fbia32.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   sda2/Boot/fbx64.efi
f62c28d9b477b6a1a7b1c991b2b6637d   sda2/Boot/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/Boot/mmx64.efi
256fe27540b54b71cf38110338247688   sda2/ubuntu/fwupx64.efi
5ddf997e8b025bfbc2009e85b32f60dc   sda2/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   sda2/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   sda2/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
20ac8dde00311476f3755604eb0e545a   sda2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
27d382c5fc21df6f4a75baed05aa1d9d   sda2/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
fecc659c3253ac65326801d790718171   sda2/Boot/BOOTIA32.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda4    : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda6    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda2    : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda4    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda6    : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda2    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda4    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda5    : maybesepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda
sda6    : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 447.1 GiB, 480103981056 bytes, 937703088 sectors
Disk identifier: 987B368E-33D5-4401-8539-89AD54404F96
          Start       End   Sectors   Size Type
sda1       2048   1023999   1021952   499M Windows recovery environment
sda2    1024000   1226751    202752    99M EFI System
sda3    1226752   1259519     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
sda4    1259520 308553727 307294208 146.5G Microsoft basic data
sda5  308553728 543018689 234464962 111.8G Linux filesystem
sda6  543019008 937701375 394682368 188.2G Linux filesystem
Disk sdb: 14.4 GiB, 15472047104 bytes, 30218842 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x01e0567d
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 30218841 30216794 14.4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
Disk zram0: 481.3 MiB, 504659968 bytes, 123208 sectors
Disk zram1: 481.3 MiB, 504659968 bytes, 123208 sectors
Disk zram2: 481.3 MiB, 504659968 bytes, 123208 sectors
Disk zram3: 481.3 MiB, 504659968 bytes, 123208 sectors

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:480GB:scsi:512:512:gpt:ATA KINGSTON SA400S3:;
1:1049kB:524MB:523MB:ntfs:Basic data partition:hidden, diag;
2:524MB:628MB:104MB:fat32:EFI System Partition:boot, esp;
3:628MB:645MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
4:645MB:158GB:157GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:158GB:278GB:120GB:ext4::;
6:278GB:480GB:202GB:ext4::;
sdb:15.5GB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 3.0:;
1:1049kB:15.5GB:15.5GB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL         PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                     
├─sda1 ntfs     226655E26655B76F                     c8d528de-8142-452d-bb7a-d4f2abf08af4 Helyreállítás Basic data partition
├─sda2 vfat     1656-892B                            faba7f17-77cf-4033-b4d6-4429680e27c0               EFI System Partition
├─sda3                                               b6c19a78-4062-4112-b983-9034751666d9               Microsoft reserved partition
├─sda4 ntfs     B61A5CE01A5C9F65                     c9315ee3-dc20-45b2-9d27-bce7d916cfe4               Basic data partition
├─sda5 ext4     70c9b5ea-c833-4a83-ad90-8c7cfa01c675 a5262dc8-76d0-4636-abe1-83d140f613d6               
└─sda6 ext4     8f41ffc2-7670-4374-9d39-8af588e0db3d 227ac73f-2d91-42ce-ae2a-a59812124399               
sdb                                                                                                     
└─sdb1 vfat     8CFA-8053                            01e0567d-01                          BOOT-REPAIR   

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

            Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1    66.8M  87% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sda2    58.9M  38% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
/dev/sda4    45.6G  69% /mnt/boot-sav/sda4
/dev/sda5   103.4G   0% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
/dev/sda6   163.7G   6% /mnt/boot-sav/sda6
/dev/sdb1    13.5G   6% /cdrom

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________


===================== sda2/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

search.fs_uuid 8f41ffc2-7670-4374-9d39-8af588e0db3d root hd0,gpt6 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

====================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   8f41ffc2-7670-4374-9d39-8af588e0db3d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-35-generic   8f41ffc2-7670-4374-9d39-8af588e0db3d
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.19.0-32-generic   8f41ffc2-7670-4374-9d39-8af588e0db3d
Windows Boot Manager (on sda2)   osprober-efi-1656-892B
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda6/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=8f41ffc2-7670-4374-9d39-8af588e0db3d /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=1656-892B  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda6/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 272.811534882 = 292.929155072  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 442.173824310 = 474.780528640  boot/vmlinuz                                   2
 440.783199310 = 473.287356416  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-32-generic                 2
 442.173824310 = 474.780528640  boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-35-generic                 2
 440.783199310 = 473.287356416  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 441.806636810 = 474.386264064  boot/initrd.img                                5
 442.857135773 = 475.514228736  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-32-generic              1
 441.806636810 = 474.386264064  boot/initrd.img-5.19.0-35-generic              5
 442.857135773 = 475.514228736  boot/initrd.img.old                            1

===================== sda6: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec  2 15:18 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec  2 15:18 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14180 Dec  2 15:18 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec  2 15:18 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec  2 15:18 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 Sep 20 03:18 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec  2 15:18 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec  2 15:18 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Boot-Repair-Disk session
Boot-Repair-Disk session (failsafe)

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
sda6,
using the following options:  sda2/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file restore-efi-backups

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS entry (sda2/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)
```

Comment: Can you scroll down in your boot manager or have a look in your BIOS? There are some Ubuntu entries, I just don't know if they are functional and visible.

Comment: well there should be an Ubuntu entry in the boot manager since I just installed it but no. Those are the only 4 things in boot manager (but I deleted fedora I think so idk) and same in BIOS (well with the extra "USB CDROM:" and stuff like that). I must have messed up my EFI drive bad but I dont even know how.

Comment: Entry `Boot0014* ubuntu` doesn't look bad. Delete the old and broken entries with `efibootmgr` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to boot into the UEFI shell, then do that and run each of the efi files directly from there. Booting into the shell usually requires interrupting the boot process to get into the BIOS and then selecting the shell from the boot menu there, but it varies depending on your computer.